# How can I improve my boot time?

Tags: startup, bootchart

I have horribly long boot time. I installed e4rat and done everything according to [this](http://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/03/17/e4rat-decreasing-bootup-time-on-hdd-drives/) tutorial. but it actually hasn't decreased the time. I tried to remove unnecessary services but I have no idea what to do now. I think 1:15 minutes is to long, I expect at least 30 sec. Here is my bootchart:

[image]

Comment: What kind of disk drives are attached to this machine? Are any of them old, external, or heavily damaged? I ask because all of the disk-related lines in the bootchart (blkid, fsck, even jbd2/sda7-8) seem to be taking more time than they should compared to a few other bootcharts available on the internet, and they frequently go into a zombie state as if they're waiting for the hardware to respond. Even `e4rat-preload`, which is supposed to load the important boot files quickly, takes over 40 seconds.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Paul. Check your disks or storage controller. Either they are faulty, not performing well in your Ubuntu version or something like that. It's almost all disk I/O wait for the CPU.